# Is it bad to rebuild Scaffold multiple times?

Tags: flutter, dart

Imagine you have a bottom navigation bar and an indexed stack to handle layout updates. Which would be the most performant code pattern?

Would rebuilding scaffold (like in second approach) cause any problems in future? with maybe text fields constantly opening and closing keyboard or something else flutter-like? Kind of hard to test everything, please tell if you had problems with this approach.

```dart
ValueNotifier<int> indexNotifier();

build => Scaffold(
  appbar: appbar(),

  body: ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: indexNotifier, 
    builder()=>body()
  ),
  bottomNavi: ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: indexNotifier, 
    builder()=>bottomNavi()
  ),
)
```

Or

```dart
ValueNotifier<int> indexNotifier();

build => ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenbable: indexNotifier,
  builder() => Scaffold(
    appbar: appbar(),

    body: body(),
    bottomNavi: bottomNavi(),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [flutter's performance best practices](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices), you should avoid having update operations too high up in your tree because when a widget re-renders all of its children re-render too. You should try to optimize your re-renders by localizing the listenable builders to where the UI actually has to change.

In your particular case, you're listening to the same `ValueNotifier` in both examples, so when an update occurs, both the body and the bottom navigation would re-render. The first example would be more performant if you were able to isolate the data on which the body depends on from the data on which the bottom navigation depends on, that way you would be avoiding unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: could you provide an example of a more performant solution given that the notifier's value is the selected bottomNavi's page?